# Retrieving user details using username from extended User Model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to retrieve the details of a user using the username **test** from an extended User model in Django. But I am unable to do it. It's giving me the error:

> ValueError at / invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test'

Following is my code:

**models.py**

```
class DocchainUser(models.Model):
    docchainuser_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default='x')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64,unique=True)   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

**views.py**

```
def my_users(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        username = request.POST.get('username') 
        user = authenticate(username=username)
        if user:
            if user.is_authenticated:
                signBool = signatureAuth(username)
                if signBool == 'AUTHENTICATED':
                    login(request, user, backend=settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS[0])
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard')
               ....
```

**And the signatureAuth() now:**

```
def signatureAuth(username):  
    userModel = DocchainUser.objects.filter(docchainuser_name=username)
    address = userModel.address
    print(address)
    ...
```

I'm retrieving the user details using **username: test** in signatureAuth() method. **test** is already present in my User as well as DocchainUser model.

Comment: Which line of code is giving the error?

Comment: Can you try:
`userModel = User.objects.filter(username=username)`

Comment: @MatthewGaiser it was in the line `userModel = DocchainUser.objects.filter(docchainuser_name=username)`. Anyways it's solved now. Thanks.

Comment: @ToniSredanović `userModel = User.objects.filter(username=username)` retrieves the user from User model while I was tring to retrieve from DocchainUser model. Anyways it's solved now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an extended user model, you have a separate model with a one-to-one relation to User. So in order to query that model by username, you need to follow the relationship.

```
userModel = DocchainUser.objects.filter(docchainuser_name__username=username)
```

Note, one of the reasons you struggled here is that your OneToOneField is probably misnamed; the relationship is with the entire model, not the username; you should call it just `docchainuser`.

(Also note, your `if user.is_authenticated` is pointless; that just checks that the user is an instance of User rather than AnonymousUser, which you know it is because you just explicitly retrieved it from the User model.)

Comment: Thank you. It's working now. Didn't knew about __username. It's returning queryset now. And thanks for the suggestions also.